# Query firebase docs by subcollection value

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firebase Firestore DB with this structure:

Users (collection) -> user (doc) -> Reports (subcollection) -> report (doc) -> `isHandled` (bool field).

In my Flutter app, I want to query `Users` collection, and get only the `user` docs in which any of their `reports` collection docs is not handled (`isHandled` field == `false`).

I've tried to use Firestore's `collectionGroup`, but it returns only 1 `report` doc, instead of many `user` docs:

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collectionGroup('Reports')
        .where(
          'isHandled',
          isEqualTo: false,
        )
        .get();
```

Does Firebase Firestore support any query of a collection by its docs' subcollection values?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-query-collections-in-firestore-under-a-certain-path-6a0d686cebd2) will also help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does Firebase Firestore support any query of a collection by its docs' subcollection values?

No.  When you query a collection or subcollection, it will only consider documents immediately within it.  The data from a single collection's documents is managed by an "index" - queries only use that index to rapidly find data at scale.

Collection group queries are special in that they consider all collections with the same name, but they will still not consider nested subcollections.

You could perhaps combine a collection group query with further queries to get the "parent" user document from a matched report.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Regarding your suggested solution approach, can you please explain a bit more about what further queries are needed in order to get the parent collection?

Comment: Use the ref in the report document snapshot to walk up to the parent document, then simply get() it.